# H2 in-memory database,[JdbcSQLException: Table "USERINFO" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: database, scala, h2, playframework-2.3, scala-2.11

i am using H2 in memory database with play framework i am a beginner so i decided to make a little Login-Register app to get started with scala and play i decided to use H2 in memory database but it throws `Table not found`exception i write an script in an sql file and play asked me to apply this script when i start the app but it throws exception when i try to insert data in it, The exception is

```
 [JdbcSQLException: Table "USERINFO" not found; SQL statement:
insert into USERINFO (fname,lname,email,userName,pwd,age,choice,gender) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [42102-175]]
```

here is the script of sql file

```
# --- !Ups
CREATE TABLE USERINFO(
    fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    userName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    pwd varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    age Int NOT NULL,
    choice varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE USERINFO;
```

and here is a section of application.conf

```
 db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
 db.default.user=sa
 db.default.password=""
 db_close_delay=-1
```

here is the code of application.scala

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import views.html.defaultpages.badRequest
import play.api.data.validation.Constraints._

import models.User



object Application extends Controller {


  val RegisterForm = Form(
mapping(

"fname" -> nonEmptyText(1, 20),
"lname" -> nonEmptyText(1, 20),
"email" -> email,
"userName" -> nonEmptyText(1, 20),
"password" -> nonEmptyText(1, 20),
"age" -> number,
"choice" -> text,
"gender" -> text

)
(User.apply)(User.unapply)
verifying("Ag should be greater then or eual to  18",model=> model.age match 
    {
  case (age) => age>=18

    })
)
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(RegisterForm))
  }

 def register =Action {implicit request => 

  RegisterForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
      hasErrors => BadRequest(views.html.index(hasErrors))
        , 
      success => {  

     val result = User.save(success)
println(s"INSERT succeeded, id = $result")
Redirect(routes.Application.index)
      }
)
}

}
```

and here is a code of User.scala

```
package models
import anorm._
import play.api.db.DB
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.Play.current

case class User (

  fname:String,
  lname:String,
  email:String,
  userName:String,
  password:String,
  age:Int,
  choice:String,
  gender:String

)
object User{

  val userinfo = {
    get[String]("fname") ~ 
    get[String]("lname") ~ 
    get[String]("email") ~ 
    get[String]("userName") ~ 
    get[String]("pwd") ~ 
    get[Int]("age") ~ 
    get[String]("choice") ~ 
    get[String]("gender") map {
    case fname ~ lname ~email~ userName ~ password ~age~ choice~gender => 
      User(fname , lname ,email, userName , password ,age, choice,gender)
  }
}
  def save(ud:User):Option[Long]= {
     val id :Option[Long] = DB.withConnection {implicit c => 
    SQL ("insert into USERINFO (fname,lname,email,userName,pwd,age,choice,gender) values ({fname},{lname},{email},{userName},{password},{age},{choice},{gender})")
    .on('fname -> ud.fname, 'lname ->ud.lname ,'email ->ud.email, 'userName->ud.userName , 'password->ud.password ,'age->ud.age, 'choice->ud.choice,'gender->ud.gender)
    .executeInsert()  
    }
    id 
  }

 /* def save(ud:User)= {
     DB.withConnection {implicit c => 
    SQL ("insert into USERINFO (fname,lname,email,userName,pwd,age,choice,gender) values ({fname},{lname},{email},{userName},{password},{age},{choice},{gender})")
    .on('fname -> ud.fname, 'lname ->ud.lname ,'email ->ud.email, 'userName->ud.userName , 'password->ud.password ,'age->ud.age, 'choice->ud.choice,'gender->ud.gender)
    .executeUpdate()  
    }

  }
 */ 
  }
```

I tried both with this `executeUpdate` and `executeInsert` but nothing changed please help me where i am doing wrong

Comment: An in-memory database is in-memory, so it goes away when you close the thing that was accessing it, and different applications get their own version. How are you executing the SQL? If you're running it in a separate process, this is exactly what we'd expect to happen; try giving it a filesystem path (`jdbc:h2:/home/users/username/mydatabase`) instead

Comment: i am taking help from [this link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTodoList)

Comment: Then yes, an in-memory database won't work for exactly that reason.

Comment: "We will use Anorm in this tutorial to query the database. First we need to define the database schema. Let’s use Play evolutions for that, so create a first evolution script in" conf/evolutions/default/1.sql

Comment: what reason sorry i can't understand  can u please explain

Comment: The h2 in-memory database doesn't persist changes. That's by design; see [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases). If you want to define your tables in this evolution way, you need the database to be persistent somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

Most likely, the problem is that the Play! Framework quotes the identifier names (table names, column names) in the query, so that you need to quote the table name in the 'create table' statement as well:

```
    CREATE TABLE "USERINFO"(
    "fname" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "lname" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "userName" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "pwd" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "age" Int NOT NULL,
    "choice" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "gender" varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

**2.**

If nothing helps. There is one more aproach.  I read the migration docs and one has to apply `libraryDependencies += evolutions` to build.sbt.

These are not necessary, they will apply the evolution automatically (without showing the Database 'default' needs evolution!):

```
applyEvolutions.db=true
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true
```